# Resetting specific form input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a radio that displays an additional input field if clicked and hides that input field if another radio is selected. What I am looking to accomplish is that when another radio input is clicked i'd like to clear that text input of any value that was put in it.

I am also utilizing MUI CSS for floating labels on form inputs which appends the `.mui--is-empty` class to fields that are empty and `.mui--is-not-empty` class to fields that contain values.

I've tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'tip-custom') {
            $('#show-me').fadeIn();           
        } else {
            $('#show-me').fadeOut();  
            $('input[name=tip-custom-value').val('');
        }
    });
 });
```

But this just sets the value to "" where I need to completely reset this specific field for the `.mui--is-empty` to append back to it.

Here's is a gyazo of what I am experiencing which you can see the starting state of the floating label and how it reacts when cleared.

https://gyazo.com/b848a5855d27b2d6ebd9202bda7fabe9

Is there a way to completely reset the text input as if there is actually no value?

**UPDATE**

I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do with the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if(this.id == 'tip-custom') {
            $('#show-me').fadeIn();           
        }
        else {
            $('#show-me').fadeOut();  
            $('input[name=tip-custom-value').val(null).removeClass('mui--is-not-empty').addClass('mui--is-empty');
        }
    });
 });
```

But i'm concerned that even if the value is set to '' will it return anything on form submit? I would prefer that if there is no actual value that it did not.

Comment: Small side note; `$(this).attr('id')` should be just `this.id`.  The two method calls are unnecessary to access that property directly.

Comment: @Taplar thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Also, without seeing working code, it's hard for me to make any suggestions for a definite answer.  But one thing I would suggest you try is adding `.trigger('change')` or `.trigger('input')` immediately after setting the value to blank.  If the MUI logic is bound to one of those events to add/remove the class, that should hopefully cause it to re-evaluate.

Comment: Have you tried $('#show-me input[type="text"]').val('');

Comment: @Taplar after digging in the mui.js it appears that the `.mui--is-empty` is triggered by the following handler: `function inputHandler() {
      var inputEl = this;
    
      if (inputEl.value.length) {
        jqLite.removeClass(inputEl, emptyClass);
        jqLite.addClass(inputEl, notEmptyClass);
      } else {
        jqLite.removeClass(inputEl, notEmptyClass);
        jqLite.addClass(inputEl, emptyClass)
      }
    }`

Comment: So it appears that its looking for any length of characters in the input field to determine which class to append.

Comment: `inputHandler` is phrase in a way that I would hope it would be attached to an `input` event handler on the input

Comment: @Taplar yes it looks like it is attached to both `input` and `change` see: `jqLite.on(inputEl, 'input change', inputHandler);` but yet when I do the following: `$('input[name=tip-custom-value').val(null).trigger('input');` it still doesnt return to the default state. It does however return to the default state if i remove the value with backspace manually...

Comment: Do you have access to the `jqLite` variable in your code?

Comment: @Taplar I'm using their js file which can be found at: https://cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.10.1/js/mui.js for you to review. The only thing I am really using from MUI is the form styles which can be found towards the bottom of that file.

Comment: @Taplar the only thing i've changed from that version to one I am using is: `var jqLite = require('./lib/jqLite'),
        util = require('./lib/util'),
        animlib = require('./lib/animationHelpers'),
        cssSelector = '.mui-textfield > input, .mui-textfield > textarea, .mui-textfield > .input-group > input',
        floatingLabelClass = 'mui-textfield--float-label';` because I have added the `.input-group` class to prepend icons.

Comment: @Taplar See updated OP

Comment: I would be curious if you could do `jqLite('input[name=tip-custom-value').val('').trigger('input')`, to use the same element, vs using the different jQuery ($) variable.

Comment: @taplar Uncaught ReferenceError: jqLite is not defined is what is being returned when trying that

Comment: Meh, well I'm running out of ideas, :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my answer is right or wrong because I cant check part of the code. I think you have a typo in your code. So, I think I could fix it. Please, check this code if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if(this.id == 'tip-custom') {
            $('#show-me').fadeIn();           
        }
        else {
            $('#show-me').fadeOut();  
            $('input[name="tip-custom-value"]').val(null).removeClass('mui--is-not-empty').addClass('mui--is-empty');
        }
    });
 });
```

The typo was inside else statement. I think you forgot to close square brackets for your code.

I hope it works.